# capture currently playing audio with HTML5?

Tags: html

Is there any way to capture the soundcard's currently playing audio with getUserMedia? As in, whatever audio is currently playing on the system. I'm pretty sure it can only access the microphone. I'm unaware if you are able to access the current soundcard output, without jacking the input to the output with something like soundflower.

Comment: Seems like that would be a pretty serious drm issue. Somehow I doubt it can be done outside an executable

Comment: I've had a similar need and am using VB-Audio Virtual Cable http://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Cable/index.htm which is free... there is nothing build into windows that allows one to capture it, some sound drivers allow you to use a software mixer where the output from the browser becomes a microphone input option. The mixer was build into win xp but removed from win 7 etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *getUserMedia* method is part of the html5 media-capture-streams specification, it will return the MediaStream object provided to it (by the user/browser). The wave output (or your default playback device) won't, or rather shouldn't, be available because it isn't a capture/input device. So, as you mentioned in your question, the way you could do this would be to use something like: 'soundflower' or 'virtual audio cables' to relay the output you wanted into a virtual input device and capture that instead.

W3 Specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/mediacapture-streams/

Alternative apps: http://alternativeto.net/software/soundflower/